# CGMiner Problems (low kh rate)

Tags: litecoin, gpu, cgminer

I have a Nvidia GTX 765 GPU, over clocked with a core KH rate of 850 (give or take a few).

When I run CGMiner, everything works fine except I have an extremely low KH rate (8 or 9 KH).

My configuration is standard, besides adding --scrypt because I'm mining LTC.

This isn't the first time I've had problems with CGMiner (gave up entirely on LTC before because of such problems) and I can't find any fix to this. The only problem I could think of is that it is using my integrated GPU, considering it claims to be using "GPU/Thread 0"

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried CBFGMiner? are your video cards bad? how much ram do you have?. how about a log?

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/3.7/SCRYPT-README

In particular:

> --intensity XX (-I XX)
>
> Just like in bitcoin mining, scrypt mining takes an intensity, however the
> scale goes from 0 to 20 to mimic the "Aggression" used in mtrlt's reaper. The
> reason this is crucial is that too high an intensity can actually be
> disastrous with scrypt because it CAN run out of ram. High intensities
> start writing over the same ram and it is highly dependent on the GPU, but they
> can start actually DECREASING your hashrate, or even worse, start producing
> garbage with HW errors skyrocketing. Note that if you do NOT specify an
> intensity, cgminer uses dynamic mode which is designed to minimise the harm
> to a running desktop and **performance WILL be poor**. The lower limit to intensity
> with scrypt is usually 8 and cgminer will prevent it going too low.
> **SUMMARY: Setting this for reasonable hashrates is mandatory.**

The author of the above is also the author of cgminer, so it is worth reading.  My results immediately improved with this:

> ./cgminer --scrypt --intensity 20 --auto-fan --gpu-powertune -10
> -u hnaparst.1 -p password -o stratum+tcp://pool1.us.multipool.us:7777